# "Cannot insert the value NULL into column" with a non-null value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

This is the code I have:

Controller action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Goal goal)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        repository.SaveGoal(goal);
        return View("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        return View(goal);
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Goal
{
    [Required]
    public int GoalId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public decimal Latitude { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public decimal Longitude { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsPrivate { get; set; }
}
```

Repository:

```
public class EFGoalRepository : IGoalRepository
{
    private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

    public IQueryable<Goal> Goals
    {
        get { return context.Goals; }
    }

    public void SaveGoal(Goal goal)
    {
        context.Goals.Add(goal);
        context.SaveChanges(); // the line which causes the exception
    }
}
```

The problem: When I try to save a new `Goal` object with `GoalId` set to `0`, I get the following error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'GoalId', table 'TravelGoals.dbo.Goals'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

I'm still new at ASP.NET MVC, but I believe this worked when I tried it a month ago with a different project.

All the values in my `Goal` object are valid (non-`null`, `Name` is of correct length). The `GoalId` property is set to `0`, so it is not `null` either. I thought that Entity Framework would automatically assign a value to it.

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Did you configure the ID to be a db generated column when you created the table in EF?

Comment: Apparently I didn't. I set the column to be identity in SQL Server, works as a charm now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I needed to do was setting the column as identity in SQL Server.

Probably the simplest way to do this (assuming you're using Visual Studio):

- Open the SQL Server Object Explorer
- Double-click the table you want to edit (or right-click and select View Designer)
- Open the Properties window
- Select the column in the Identity Column property as shown below

[image: Properties window showing the Identity Column property]

Comment: If you're going to answer your own question I'd suggest adding a bit more detail about where/what etc so it's useful for future readers

Answer (score 1):

Problem is `GoalId` is not identity.Put this attribut on `GoalId`

```
[Key]
public int GoalId { get; set; }
```

If your EF version is lower than 5 use this:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int GoalId { get; set; }
```